# loading jquery plugins into a specific namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, labjs

I'm considering loading jquery and a series of plugins via a loader i.e labjs, or yepnope.js.

I want to load the jquery plugins into a custom jquery namespace, if possible without modifying them.

Any idea how I could load these plugins without having to modify them by adding a (mynamespace.Jquery) *efficiently*?

Answer (score 1):

How you can load them into the namespace is easy enough:

```
(function(jQuery) {

-- Plugin code here

})(mynamespace.jQuery);
```

The second part of your question is a little harder.  Say your plugin resides on the server at http://www.mysite.com/javascript/jquery.fancybox.js

You're going to have to serve the plugin. You're going to have to dynamically wrap the plugin somehow within your desired namespace.

Quick pseudo code answer in php:

1. An example request would be to
   http://www.mysite.com/plugin.php?script=jquery.fancybox&namespace=mynamespace
2. In plugin.php, read in the JS file contents from the
   $_REQUEST['script'] param
3. Output the file contents in the wrapper, e.g.

(function(jQuery) {

< ?= $scriptFileContents ?>

})(< ?= $_REQUEST['namespace'] ?>.jQuery);

And *obviously* you're going to escape the input parameters to not allow for XSS attacks, right?